# Which server name should one use for ServerName apache config?

Tags: apache-httpd, webserver, apache-virtualhost

Which server name should i use for ServerName apache config if i am hosting multiple subdomains on the same host. Trying to get rid of this warning in the /var/log/apache/error.log file

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using ip_address_goes_here. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Which one should take precedence?

- www.nicehost.com
- super.nicehost.com
- hehe.nicehost.com
- nicehost.com

Thanks

Comment: you're asking which one YOU prefer? how can anyone here know that?

Comment: well i thought it mattered but since you say it doesn't, then i will just pick one

Comment: wait, i just looked at my virtual host configs and ServerName is defined numerous times, should there only be one ServerName and the rest of the subdomains should just be aliases? Is Apache confused since there are multiple ServerName config lines across virtual host files.

Comment: if they're all just different names for the **same** web site, then using one vhost definition with multiple `ServerAlias`es would be good.  The `ServerName` defines the **canonical** name for the host.  If not, then no - each vhost needs its own config.    BTW, if all the hostnames are just aliases for the one web site then you don't really need a VirtualHost definition, you can do everything in the server's global config......either way, to get rid of that error message, you must have a ServerName definition in the global config.

Comment: got it, thanks, all my ServerName declarations are in their own VirtualHosts since they are all different services and run different code, however i do not have one declared outside of my VirtualHost definitions